# Encrypting SMS and calls

Tags: sms, calls, encryption, privacy

Is it possible to encrypt calls and SMS messages between two Android phones (or even from android to iPhone)?

This firm delivered a beta on Android Market before: http://www.whispersys.com/

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/329/what-voice-privacy-apps-are-available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RedPhone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.redphone) and [TextSecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.securesms) from WhisperSystems are the best way to achieve encrypted voice and SMS on android.

Those two apps Just Work (tm) and are extremely user friendly.

Comment: Cool, they have released it now :)

But now i get a problem when registring with redphone, it says "you must specify your number in international format, eg: +14151231234". But i did. Strange...

Answer (score 4):

What you want is [Zfone](http://zfoneproject.com/) on Android. It is currently not native available, [but there is a bug report on the offical Android tracker asking for it.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13305) Star it, but don't leave a comment *without content.* This is the best chance to raise Googles attentions on this.

Whats currently possible on Android is good described by the guardian project [in this blog post.](https://guardianproject.info/2010/05/26/how-to-setup-a-private-mobile-phone-system-for-android-and-beyond/) BTW: [The Guardian Project](https://guardianproject.info/) is good resource when it comes to to privacy and security on Android.